# ffmpeg zoompan overlay resets zoom after some seconds

Tags: ffmpeg

I noticed that sometimes (not always) my zoompan resets the zoom to the starting size after some seconds.

In this case I have the image with fade in - fade out and zoom during all the time.

My image should appear at 22'' (and it is) and disappear at 41''(and it works also). (total 19'')

The image keep zooming all the time, but exactly at 38'' (after 16 seconds) it goes back to the first size and it restart zooming. I tried changing the zoompan value, the duration and the timings, but it still resets the size.

What am I missing?

```
-i "output_text2.mp4" -loop 1 -t 1 -i "1.png" -filter_complex "[1:v]format=yuva422p,scale=1115x1980,setsar=1/1,pad=1.5*iw:1.5*ih:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:color=black@0,zoompan=z='zoom+0.0005':s=223x396:d=475:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)',fade=in:st=22:d=3:alpha=1,fade=out:st=38:d=3:alpha=1[im];[0][im]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h - overlay_h)/2:shortest=1" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output_0.mp4
```

thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `-loop 1 -t 1` before `-i "1.png"`.

Change fade timings and add PTS filter

`fade=in:st=0:d=3:alpha=1,fade=out:st=16:d=3:alpha=1,setpts=PTS+22/TB[im]`

To paraphrase an earlier answer,

zoompan operates on each image individually. By adding -t 1 before each image, it will operate upon 25 frames of each image, producing, for each, a zoompan of 475 frames! I don't think this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks, and thanks also for the explaination! this software can't hide anything to you :)

Comment: one stuff: after the fade out, the video is stopped and it goes on until the end with the same frame as the one after the fade out ends. You know why?

Comment: got it sorry, it is because I had to remove only `-t 1` and not `-loop 1`, if it is correct, can you edit the answer? thanks again

Comment: No, remove `shortest=1` from overlay.